# Debug MySQL deadlock?

Tags: sql, mysql, deadlock

A deadlock had occurred in MySQL after changing a stored procedure. It was occurred 3 days ago and the stored procedure was reverted. Is there a way to check logs how it occurred and to debug it?
Because can't find anything on MySQL, just know that deadlock was occurred in the SP 3 days ago and it was reverted earlier.

I had a asked a question and expect to get answer on it.

Comment: May I first ask what you mean by "deadlock"? If you're seeing a specific error message then post that. Also please tell us how familiar you are with concepts like row-locking and transaction-isolation. And you probably should post the procedure itself and show us what was changed.

Comment: The first duplicate shows how you can get the information to debug a deadlock, the 2nd shows a sample question that helps you to interpret the debug tool's output.